Crop a raster file using a shapefile in R
I have a raster file with the following attributes:
rstack_ET[[1]] # first layer from a stacked raster
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 334, 733, 244822  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 409, 498  (x, y)
extent     : 386067.5, 685864.5, 3805999, 3972331  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=utm +zone=36 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : ET.1.1.1.1.1 
values     : 70, 674.7922  (min, max)

and I am using a polygon, obtained from a shapefile, with the following attributes:
> dom_shp_sr
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 11 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XYZ
Bounding box:  xmin: 490187.9 ymin: 3837447 xmax: 499269.9 ymax: 3852987
z_range:       zmin: 0 zmax: 0
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 36N
                          Name descriptio timestamp begin  end altitudeMo tessellate extrude visibility drawOrder icon
1 recharge limestones-akrotiri       <NA>      <NA>  <NA> <NA>       <NA>          1       0         -1        NA <NA>
                        geometry
1 POLYGON Z ((490233.2 383762...

The polgon looks like this:

When I am trying to use the polygon to crop the raster file:
test = crop(rstack_ET[[1]], dom_shp_sr)

I get the following image:

So, it uses the extent of the polygon to crop the raster file, but not the actual shape of the polygon.
Any help is appreciated.

wouldn't be easier to use crop function instead ? crop(ET_sr_r, dom_shp_sr). [] is a shorthand notation that will do a crop behind but expects a SpatialXXX vectorial object and you are providing an sf object

@Billy34 thanks. When I do that, it only uses the extent of dom_shp_sr (I get a rectangular raster) whereas the polygon is irregular (not a rectangular shape). See the image in the updated post

then you can mask the result and get what you want. mask(crop(ET_sr_r, dom_shp_sr), dom_shp_sr)). By using terra package that is superseding raster package, you'll get an all-in-one function crop which has a mask parameter for that :-)

@Billy34 after I installed terra package,  I run the command library(terra ); test = terra::mask( crop(ET_sr_r, dom_shp_sr), dom_shp_sr ), I get the following message: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'addAttrToGeom': sp supports Z dimension only for POINT and MULTIPOINT.
use st_zm(...) to coerce to XY dimensions

@Billy34 I found it. I had to just as st_zm(dom_shp_sr) instead of dom_shp_sr. Thanks!

Using terra package
# ensure your raster is a terra raster if not already
ET_sr_r <- terra::rast(ET_sr_r)

# I think crop expects a SpatVector so cast sf object as vect
masked_ET <- terra::crop(ET_sr_r, vect(dom_shp_sr), mask=TRUE)

Using raster package
masked_ET <- raster::mask(raster::crop(ET_sr_r, dom_shp_sr), dom_shp_sr)

